# Pandas - compute new colum based on the relative value in other rows

Tags: python, pandas

With data like below

```
data = """
Class,Location,Long,Lat
A,ABC11,139.6295542,35.61144069
A,ABC20,139.630596,35.61045559
A,ABC03,139.6300307,35.61327781
B,ABC54,139.7787818,35.68847945
B,ABC05,139.7814447,35.6816882
B,ABC06,139.7788191,35.681865
B,ABC24,139.7790396,35.67781697
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
```

Each row contains data pertaining to a location. For each location, need to find the distance to other locations (rows) as follows (simplified for ease)

```
distance = sqrt((Long1-Long2)^2 + (Lat1-Lat2)^2)
```

if it was done outside pandas I would do as follows

```
import math

rows = df.to_dict('records')

# distance of each location w.r.t other locations excluding self
results = {}
for row in rows:
    loc = row['Location']
    results[loc] = {}
    # get a new list excl the curr row
    nrows = [row for row in rows if row['Location'] != loc]
    for nrow in nrows:
        dist = math.sqrt((row["Long"] - nrow["Long"])**2 + (row["Lat"] - nrow["Lat"])**2)
        results[loc][nrow["Location"]] = dist

# find the location with min distance 
fin_results = {}
for k, v in results.items():
    fin_results[k] = {}
    minValKey = min(v, key = v.get)
    fin_results[k]["location"] = minValKey 
    fin_results[k]["dist"] = v[minValKey]
```

This would give an output like below which for each location gives the location which is the most nearest and distance to that location.

```
{'ABC11': {'location': 'ABC20', 'dist': 0.001433795400325211}, 'ABC20': {'location': 'ABC11', 'dist': 0.001433795400325211}, 'ABC03': {'location': 'ABC11', 'dist': 0.001897909941062068}, 'ABC54': {'location': 'ABC06', 'dist': 0.006614555169662396}, 'ABC05': {'location': 'ABC06', 'dist': 0.002631545857463665}, 'ABC06': {'location': 'ABC05', 'dist': 0.002631545857463665}, 'ABC24': {'location': 'ABC06', 'dist': 0.004054030973106164}}
```

While this works functionally, wanted to know what would be the `pandas` way of doing this.

The desired output

```
+----------+-------------------+----------------------------+
| location |  nearest_location |  nearest_location_distance |
+----------+-------------------+----------------------------+
| 'ABC11'  | 'ABC20'           | 0.001433795400325211       |
| 'ABC20'  | 'ABC11'           | 0.001433795400325211       |
| 'ABC03'  | 'ABC11'           | 0.001897909941062068       |
| 'ABC54'  | 'ABC06'           | 0.006614555169662396       |
| 'ABC05'  | 'ABC06'           | 0.002631545857463665       |
| 'ABC06'  | 'ABC05'           | 0.002631545857463665       |
| 'ABC24'  | 'ABC06'           | 0.004054030973106164       |
+----------+-------------------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy` broadcasting

```
long_ = df.Long.to_numpy()
lat   = df.Lat.to_numpy() 

distances = np.sqrt((long_ - long_[:, None]) ** 2 + (lat - lat[:,None]) **2)

dist_df = pd.DataFrame(distances, index=df.Location, columns=df.Location)
```

```
Location     ABC11     ABC20     ABC03     ABC54     ABC05     ABC06     ABC24

ABC11     0.000000  0.001434  0.001898  0.167940  0.167348  0.165044  0.163559
ABC20     0.001434  0.000000  0.002878  0.167472  0.166822  0.164528  0.163012
ABC03     0.001898  0.002878  0.000000  0.166680  0.166151  0.163836  0.162385
ABC54     0.167940  0.167472  0.166680  0.000000  0.007295  0.006615  0.010666
ABC05     0.167348  0.166822  0.166151  0.007295  0.000000  0.002632  0.004558
ABC06     0.165044  0.164528  0.163836  0.006615  0.002632  0.000000  0.004054
ABC24     0.163559  0.163012  0.162385  0.010666  0.004558  0.004054  0.000000
```

```
m = dist_df[dist_df>0]
pd.concat([m.idxmin(1).rename('nearest_location'),
           m.min(1).rename('nearest_location_distance'), ],1)
```

The output data frame would be something like

```
        nearest_location  nearest_location_distance
Location                                            
ABC11               ABC20                   0.001434
ABC20               ABC11                   0.001434
ABC03               ABC11                   0.001898
ABC54               ABC06                   0.006615
ABC05               ABC06                   0.002632
ABC06               ABC05                   0.002632
ABC24               ABC06                   0.004054
```

---

This will find the distance from one row to *all* others. That's how I had interpreted the question, not sure if is your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy`'s `distance_matrix`, which is actually what @rafaelc coded:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

dist_mat = distance_matrix(df[['Long','Lat']],df[['Long','Lat']])

# assign distance matrix with appropriate name
dist_mat = pd.DataFrame(dist_mat, 
                        index=df.Location, 
                        columns=df.Location)

# convert the data frame to dict
(dist_mat.where(dist_mat>0)
     .agg(('idxmin', 'min'))
     .to_dict()
)
```

Output:

```
{'ABC11': {'idxmin': 'ABC20', 'min': 0.001433795400325211},
 'ABC20': {'idxmin': 'ABC11', 'min': 0.001433795400325211},
 'ABC03': {'idxmin': 'ABC11', 'min': 0.001897909941062068},
 'ABC54': {'idxmin': 'ABC06', 'min': 0.006614555169662396},
 'ABC05': {'idxmin': 'ABC06', 'min': 0.002631545857463665},
 'ABC06': {'idxmin': 'ABC05', 'min': 0.002631545857463665},
 'ABC24': {'idxmin': 'ABC06', 'min': 0.004054030973106164}}    ​
```

If you want the dataframe only:

```
(dist_mat.where(dist_mat>0)
     .agg(('idxmin', 'min'))
     .T
)
```

Output:

```
      idxmin         min
ABC11  ABC20   0.0014338
ABC20  ABC11   0.0014338
ABC03  ABC11  0.00189791
ABC54  ABC06  0.00661456
ABC05  ABC06  0.00263155
ABC06  ABC05  0.00263155
ABC24  ABC06  0.00405403
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [df.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
distance_min=[]
location_min=[]
output_df=df.copy()
for i, col in df.iterrows():
    dist=((col['Long']-df['Long']).pow(2)+(col['Lat']-df['Lat']).pow(2)).pow(1/2)
    location_min.append(df.at[dist[dist>0].idxmin(),'Location'])
    distance_min.append(dist[dist>0].min())

output_df['nearest_location']=location_min
output_df['nearest_location_distance']=distance_min
output_df=output_df.reindex(columns=['Location','nearest_location','nearest_location_distance'])
print(output_df)
```

---

```
 Location  nearest_location  nearest_location_distance
0    ABC11            ABC20                   0.001434
1    ABC20            ABC11                   0.001434
2    ABC03            ABC11                   0.001898
3    ABC54            ABC06                   0.006615
4    ABC05            ABC06                   0.002632
5    ABC06            ABC05                   0.002632
6    ABC24            ABC06                   0.004054
```

Answer (score 0):

As  ansev  propose the same  solution a bit more finished

```
import pandas as pd 
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
df['result']= (df['Lat'].diff(-1).pow(2)+df['Long'].diff(-1).pow(2)).pow(1/2)
```